# Error handling using async/q/promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm new to using node.js and right now I'm working on an API which queries mongodb.

The following function apiRequest needs to call two functions, each of which performs a seperate db query.The problem with the current function is that if one of the query has some sort of error, I wouldnt be able to catch it.

What is the best way to implement this so its properly error handled. Someone pointed me to the async library and mentioned that I had to do something with promises but I really cant figure it out. Ideally I wouldnt want to change the definition of dbQueryOne and dbQueryTwo since they are being used in other places aswell.

```
exports.apiRequest =function(req,res) {
  dbQueryOne(req.body.inputA);
  dbQueryTwo(req.body.inputA);
  res.send('Moved For Further Action',200);
}
```

Comment: *"...I wouldnt be able to catch it."* Why not? Either the function you're calling is synchronous, in which you use `try/catch`, or (probably the case here) it's asynchronous, in which case it gives you a mechanism to find out that an error occurred. (Which might involve promises, or might not; in NodeJS, at the moment, typically not but that's rapidly changing.)

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.apiRequest = function(req,res) {
  dbFuncs = [dbQueryOne(req.body.inputA), dbQueryTwo(req.body.inputA)];
  Promise.all(dbFuncs)
  .then(result => { 
    res.send('Moved For Further Action',200);
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    //catch err
  });
}
```

You can use promise.all to run multiple queries and catch any error that has occurred in the catch block